# What's the best continuation for white here?

Tags: opening, learning, strategy, petroff-defense

Here's what I do when someone tries to copy my moves:

```
[Date "????.??.??"]
[Result "*"]
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nf6 3.Nxe5 Nxe4 4.Qe2 Qe7 5.Qxe4 d6 
*
```

But then my opponent plays `d6`, and I don't know what should I do. What's the best continuation for white after `d6`?

Comment: `6.d4` with the simple idea of holding onto the `e5` pawn. Your next should be `Bf4` -> `Bc4` -> `0-0`, with winning position.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff But what if black plays `f6` after i play `e5`?

Comment: `Bf4` and proceed as user *Tony Ennis* said in his answer. I will try to get time to answer your question with concrete lines, I am in a mess right now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not down material, so just develop.

`6.d4` allows both your bishops to get in the game while keeping strength in the center. After that, you can develop your minor pieces and castle very efficiently. You're going to have a swell game.

I wouldn't worry too much about `7... f6`. That move weakens his Kingside. And since you're up a pawn, the best he can do is retake on `e5` and give himself an isolated pawn. `8. Bf4` develops a piece and puts an eye on the under-defended `c7` square.

Furthermore, after `Bf4`, you can plan for `Nc3` followed by `O-O-O` (castling on the queenside) where your rook will thunder on the `d` file.

Comment: The only other thing this answer needs is: http://androida.s3.amazonaws.com/appimages/92/26/a562e846d4f01c0eb845205a83.c.png :-)